# Answering My Own Question With A Self-Made Homebrew

Tags: support, questions, accepted-answer

What if,
1. No one has really given an answer to my question (or no answer worked)
2. My group figured out a homebrew solution on our own and played it.
3. That answer was the best and solved the problem.

Is it acceptable to post that answer myself, on my own question, and explain what we did, and then check "answer" on the post?

Answer (score 11):

Yes, as long as your question allowed for homebrew.

This is the intended behavior of the system.